# Android: skipping the user particulars input page the second time he launches it

Tags: android, android-intent

I have three activities where the first activity is the welcome app page(SavingsGuiderSplashActivity) which will animate to the second activity which will ask for the username(SavingsGuiderUserActivity). I used shared preference to store the username. then after clicking the submit button, it will go to the menu page(SavingsGuiderMenuActivity). ive declared retrieve preference method in the second page so when the user launches the app again, if the prefs contain the username, it will directly go to the main menu activity page instead of the second activity which asked for the username.I think the problem concerns more on the SavingsGuiderSplashActivity and also the SavingsGuiderUserActivity. I have no problem in displaying the name on the menu page though. eg.("Hi John"). I tried to produce this but somehow the second time I start the app, it will still go to the second page. can anybody tell me whats wrong with my codes?

My animated welcome page codes:

```
public class SavingsGuiderSplashActivity extends SavingsActivity {


EditText nameEdit;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    startAnimating();
}

private void startAnimating() {
    // Fade in top title
    TextView img1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewTopTitle);
    Animation fade1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in);
    img1.startAnimation(fade1);
    // Fade in bottom title after a built-in delay.
   TextView img2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewBottomTitle);

    Animation fade2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in2);
    img2.startAnimation(fade2);

    // Transition to Main Menu when bottom title finishes animating
    fade2.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

            // The animation has ended, transition to the Main Menu screen              

                 startActivity(new Intent(SavingsGuiderSplashActivity.this, SavingsGuiderUserActivity.class));
            SavingsGuiderSplashActivity.this.finish();
        }


    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }});

    // Load animations for all views within the TableLayout

    Animation spinin = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.custom_anim);
    LayoutAnimationController controller = new LayoutAnimationController(spinin);
    TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);
    for (int i = 0; i < table.getChildCount(); i++) {
        TableRow row = (TableRow) table.getChildAt(i);
        row.setLayoutAnimation(controller);

    }
}


        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            // Stop the animation
            TextView img1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewTopTitle);
            img1.clearAnimation();
            TextView img2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewBottomTitle);
            img2.clearAnimation();

            TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);
            for (int i = 0; i < table.getChildCount(); i++) {
                TableRow row = (TableRow) table.getChildAt(i);
                row.clearAnimation();



        }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();

            // Start animating at the beginning 
            startAnimating();

        }
```

}

My user activity page here:

```
public class SavingsGuiderUserActivity extends SavingsActivity {
 /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    String tag = "SavingsGuiderActivity";
    EditText nameEdit;
    Toast toast;        

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
    retrievePreferences();
    setContentView(R.layout.user);        

    Button submitBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_submit);
    nameEdit=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_name);

    submitBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {           
        public void onClick(View v) {
                String txt = nameEdit.getText().toString();                  

                //validate the editText
                if (!txt.equals("")) {                      
                Intent intent = new Intent(SavingsGuiderUserActivity.this, SavingsGuiderMenuActivity.class);
                Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                extras.putString("name",txt);
                intent.putExtras(extras);
                saveAsPreferences();
                startActivity(intent);

                } 
                else {
                    Context context = getApplicationContext();
                    CharSequence text = "Please enter your name!";
                    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                    toast.show();
                }                   

        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d(tag, "In the onDestroy() event");
}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();

    Log.d(tag, "In the onPause() event");
}
@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onRestart();
    Log.d(tag, "In the onRestart() event");
    retrievePreferences();
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();       
    Log.d(tag, "In the onResume() event");
    retrievePreferences();
}
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart();
    Log.d(tag, "In the onStart() event");
    retrievePreferences();
}
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStop();
    Log.d(tag, "In the onStop() event");
}
public void saveAsPreferences(){
String nameString = nameEdit.getText().toString();
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString("name", nameString);
}
public void retrievePreferences(){
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("preferences",MODE_PRIVATE);
if(prefs.contains("name")){
String nameString = prefs.getString("name", "");
nameEdit.setText(nameString);
Intent intent = new Intent(SavingsGuiderUserActivity.this, SavingsGuiderMenuActivity.class);
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
intent.putExtras(extras);
startActivity(intent);
}

}
```

}

My menu page here:

```
public class SavingsGuiderMenuActivity extends SavingsActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    String name= bundle.getString("name");
```

TextView resultView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.view_Name);

```
    resultView.setText("Welcome " + name);

    ListView menuList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView_Menu);
    String[] items = { getResources().getString(R.string.start),
            getResources().getString(R.string.about),
            getResources().getString(R.string.help) };
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.menu_item, items);
    menuList.setAdapter(adapt);
    menuList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View itemClicked, int position, long id) {
            // Note: if the list was built "by hand" the id could be used.
            // As-is, though, each item has the same id
            TextView textView = (TextView) itemClicked;
            String strText = textView.getText().toString();
            if (strText.equalsIgnoreCase(getResources().getString(R.string.start))) {
                // Launch the Game Activity
                startActivity(new Intent(SavingsGuiderMenuActivity.this, SavingsGuiderAppActivity.class));
            } else if (strText.equalsIgnoreCase(getResources().getString(R.string.help))) {
                // Launch the Help Activity
                startActivity(new Intent(SavingsGuiderMenuActivity.this, SavingsGuiderHelpActivity.class));
            } else if (strText.equalsIgnoreCase(getResources().getString(R.string.about))) {
                // Launch the Settings Activity
                startActivity(new Intent(SavingsGuiderMenuActivity.this, SavingsGuiderAboutActivity.class));
            } 
        }
    });
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try retrieving your preferences in the first page itself (i.e on the SavingsGuiderSplashActivity) and see if the username exists. Use the following function

```
public boolean usernameExists()
{
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("preferences",MODE_PRIVATE);
if(prefs.contains("name"))
{
return true;
}
else
{
return false;
}
}
```

Wait, I'll just change your SavingsGuiderSplashActivity code for you

```
public class SavingsGuiderSplashActivity extends SavingsActivity {


EditText nameEdit;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.splash);
startAnimating();
}


 private void startAnimating() {
// Fade in top title
TextView img1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewTopTitle);
Animation fade1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in);
img1.startAnimation(fade1);
// Fade in bottom title after a built-in delay.
TextView img2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewBottomTitle);

Animation fade2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in2);
img2.startAnimation(fade2);

// Transition to Main Menu when bottom title finishes animating
fade2.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

        // The animation has ended, transition to the Main Menu screen              

         if(!usernameExists())
         {
             startActivity(new Intent(SavingsGuiderSplashActivity.this, SavingsGuiderUserActivity.class));
         }
          else
          {
             startActivity(new Intent(SavingsGuiderSplashActivity.this, SavingsGuiderMenuActivity.class));
          }
        SavingsGuiderSplashActivity.this.finish();
    }

public boolean usernameExists()
{
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("preferences",MODE_PRIVATE);
if(prefs.contains("name"))
{
return true;
}
else
{
return false;
}
} 

@Override
public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}});

// Load animations for all views within the TableLayout

Animation spinin = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.custom_anim);
LayoutAnimationController controller = new LayoutAnimationController(spinin);
TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);
for (int i = 0; i < table.getChildCount(); i++) {
    TableRow row = (TableRow) table.getChildAt(i);
    row.setLayoutAnimation(controller);

 }
}


    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        // Stop the animation
        TextView img1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewTopTitle);
        img1.clearAnimation();
        TextView img2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewBottomTitle);
        img2.clearAnimation();

        TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);
        for (int i = 0; i < table.getChildCount(); i++) {
            TableRow row = (TableRow) table.getChildAt(i);
            row.clearAnimation();



    }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // Start animating at the beginning 
        startAnimating();

    }
```

This should fix it!

Comment: thank you! Do i need to delete off any codes from other activity page or do I just add in the codes above?

Comment: Hey, Ive tried but it still prompts for the username the second time it launches... actually the second time i launched, it went to the user page n skipped the splash animation page..

Comment: That's really strange. You need to delete retrievePreferences in user page. You only have to check if the username exists in the 1st page so that if it exists you can just skip to the third page. That's what this code does if(!usernameExists())
         {
             startActivity(new Intent(SavingsGuiderSplashActivity.this, SavingsGuiderUserActivity.class));
         }
          else
          {
             startActivity(new Intent(SavingsGuiderSplashActivity.this, SavingsGuiderMenuActivity.class));
          }

Comment: yeah abit strange. Im not sure whats the second output is going to be because there is this message in the console when i launch it again "[2012-07-26 20:45:24 - SavingsGuider] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=nyp.edu.Savings/.SavingsGuiderSplashActivity }
[2012-07-26 20:45:24 - SavingsGuider] ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front"

Comment: okay i found out the reason already. it is because I didnt do the edotir.commit() function in my saveprefs method. secondly, the splash activity couldnt pass the username value to the menu page as i didnt put in any bundle in the if statement. All the same, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of retrieve preferences if you have a username, try putting:

```
this.finish();
```

Comment: You mean in the user activity page, in the retrieve prefs method right after startActivity(intent);, I place this.finish(); ?

Comment: Okay ive added it in. First time I launch the app, it prompts for my name. after I key in, it directs me to the menu page. then when i press the hardware back button all the way to the android home page and restart my app, it still prompts me for my name..

Answer (score 0):

If i understand it correctly, second time you want to directly move from **SavingsGuiderSplashActivity** --> **SavingsGuiderMenuActivity**, there by skipping **SavingsGuiderUserActivity**. If that is true then in your **SavingsGuiderSplashActivity's** onAnimationEnd method you need to check if preference value is set and based on that you need launch appropriate activity,

Comment: yes you are correct. But how do I check them? Do I need it to re-declare the shared and retrieve all over again in the splash activity and then do the if else statement?

Answer (score 0):

So this is what my teacher taught me to get amy app running!

User activity page

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.user);        

    Button submitBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_submit);
    nameEdit=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_name);

    submitBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {           
        public void onClick(View v) {
                String txt = nameEdit.getText().toString();                  

                //validate the editText
                if (!txt.equals("")) {                      
                Intent intent = new Intent(SavingsGuiderUserActivity.this, SavingsGuiderMenuActivity.class);
                Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                extras.putString("name",txt);
                intent.putExtras(extras);
                saveAsPreferences();
                startActivity(intent);

                } 
                else {
                    Context context = getApplicationContext();
                    CharSequence text = "Please enter your name!";
                    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                    toast.show();
                }                   

        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d(tag, "In the onDestroy() event");
}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();

    Log.d(tag, "In the onPause() event");
}
@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onRestart();
    Log.d(tag, "In the onRestart() event");
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();       
    Log.d(tag, "In the onResume() event");
}
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart();
    Log.d(tag, "In the onStart() event");
}
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStop();
    Log.d(tag, "In the onStop() event");
}
public void saveAsPreferences(){
String nameString = nameEdit.getText().toString();
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.clear();
editor.putString("name", nameString);
editor.commit();
}
}
```

Splash activity:

```
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

            // The animation has ended, transition to the Main Menu screen
            if(!usernameExists())
            {
                startActivity(new Intent(SavingsGuiderSplashActivity.this, SavingsGuiderUserActivity.class));
            }
             else
             {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SavingsGuiderSplashActivity.this, SavingsGuiderMenuActivity.class);
                Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                extras.putString("name",strName);
                intent.putExtras(extras);
                startActivity(intent);                 
             }
           SavingsGuiderSplashActivity.this.finish();
       }

   public boolean usernameExists()
   {
   SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("preferences",MODE_PRIVATE);
   if(prefs.contains("name"))
   {
       strName = prefs.getString("name", null);
   return true;
   }
   else
   {
   return false;
   }
   }
```

Comment: What's the point of accepting my answer and then modifying it slightly and unaccepting my answer and posting it as your own answer? You could have just asked me to edit my code with these 4 lines.                 Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                extras.putString("name",strName);
                intent.putExtras(extras);
                startActivity(intent);

Comment: Show some respect for the effort that people on SO put into answering your questions.

Comment: Ive accepted! the tick is in green color! Im sorry if I have offended you because Im just new to this website! Initially I ticked all the answers people gave me fyi then I found out I can only tick out hence the "untick notification". Then i immediately ticked your answer because without the codes you gave me, i would get stuck until now. And the green tick has been there all along I swear.

Comment: okay ive done a re-check and been ticking n unticking stuffs. I hope that a notification has been sent to you already. once again, I apologize.

Comment: don't worry about it, I know you are new to SO. I  was just trying to educate you on what would be considered good practices on this website. You should upvote answers if you think they've helped you and then accept one answer that you think answers your question most comprehensively. Cheers and welcome to SO! :)